# TVITEM LPARAM to store string

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview, common-controls, lparam

I've got a treeview listing files that are dropped upon it.

When I make a new treeview item, I'd like to store the address of the file as a string in that item, and retrieve it for various nefarious purposes at a later point in time.

Looking at the [TVITEM structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Microsoft docs, apparently `LPARAM` is the place to store a value:

> lParam
>
> ```
> Type: LPARAM
>
> A value to associate with the item.
> ```

So, I have gone ahead and done that:

```
TVITEM tvi;
tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
tvi.pszText = const_cast<char *> (str0.c_str());
tvi.cchTextMax = sizeof(tvi.pszText);
tvi.lParam = (LPARAM) foo;  // SETTING LPARAM HERE, foo IS A const char * 

TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis;
tvis.item = tvi;
tvis.hInsertAfter = 0;
tvis.hParent = hti0;

// Send message to update tree, and return tree item.
return TreeView_InsertItem(tvw_filelist_, &tvis);
```

Then, when I try to retrieve my value...

```
HTREEITEM htiSel = TreeView_GetSelection(tvw_filelist_);

TVITEM tvItem;
tvItem.hItem = htiSel;

TreeView_GetItem(tvw_filelist_, &tvItem);
const char * info = (const char *) tvItem.lParam;
MessageBox(NULL, info, "Alert", MB_OK);
```

...I just get garbage, indicating my pointer went out of scope or is taking a nap or something.  The size of that pointer is always 4.

Is this the right way to do what I'm trying to do? If so, what's going on?

Comment: Well, it depends on what foo is. Your code seems a little odd - if foo is a pointer to some text, then you're storing the address of that pointer, as opposed to the address of the data it points to. (the pointer's value)

Comment: Yeah, that was fluctuating around in my various experiments...thanks and sorry.  Editing code now.  Turns out that wasn't the main problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, take the time to post a question after a long time trying to figure it out, and the answer shows up in seconds.

Turns out the TVITEM mask needs to include TVIF_PARAM, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707516/sendmessage-lparam-empty).

If I change the above code to:

```
tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;
```

it works as expected.

<s>I'm still not sure if this is the recommended use for LPARAM, though.</s>

Comment: Yeah, you an use it for anything you like that fits into 32 bits. If it's 4 chars or an int - great, just put em in. If it's anything larger, just store a pointer to the data there. LParam is for anything you please. I've used it in the past to hold structs that represent the material used to render a 3d ball, displayed as the image for each item in the list. This then allows me to use a custom sort function to sort on Hue, Sat or Lum - or of course anything else I like. :) glad you got it sorted.

Comment: I think you should "wrap" you text string into the structure, and store a pointer to it in `LPARAM` - instead of string itself. This can be useful in future then you decide to expand your custom data with some new params.

Comment: @Axilles - you can do that?!!!! Something to try out tomorrow (already 8 hours today, eyes bleeding).

Comment: @Steve Sure. See my answer below.

Comment: @enhzflep: *"you [c]an use [`lParam`] for anything you like that fits into 32 bits"* - The `LPARAM` data type is pointer-sized, i.e. 32 bits on a 32-bit system, 64 bits on a 64-bit system. This is an important detail. As written, your comment suggests, that you could store a pointer into *lParam* on 32-bit systems only.

Comment: @IInspectable - thanks for the correction for everyone else's sake. I'd long since forgotten giving that piece of unclear/misleading advice.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct CustomTreeData
{
    LPSTR str;   // or even std::string to forget about memory managment
    // TODO: any other data you need
};
...
TVITEM tvi;
tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;

CustomTreeData* myDataPtr = new CustomTreeData;   // the memory should be free later
myDataPtr->str = stringWhatIWant;   // And don't forget to alloc memory for str!
tvi.lParam = (LPARAM) myDataPtr;
```

I  don't check this code, but it should work. Happy coding :)

Comment: Sorry to accept my own answer when you were so helpful, but my answer answers the original question :)  Thanks though +1